# Rasterio reprojection, changing pixel size: results in crazy pixel values

Tags: python, coordinate-system, rasterio, dimensions

I'm trying to project a geotiff with 789x789m pixel size to 100mx100m using another geotiff as a template. Everything seems to work except that the output pixel values, shown when I open the file in QGIS, are 1.79769e+308 to -1.79769e+308 (inputs are between 890-1776). I'm not changing the CRS...and the dimensions, origin, pixel size and extent of the output file look right. What am I doing wrong? I'm very much a Python beginner so it's probably very simple.

```
from natsort import natsorted
import os
import rasterio
from rasterio.warp import calculate_default_transform, reproject, Resampling

template = file_dir+'/NG_boundary.tif'

list_test_files=[]
names_test=[]
dst_crs = 'EPSG:32554'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(file_dir+"/test"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.tif') and "boundary" not in file and "projected" not in file:
            list_test_files.append(file_dir+"/test/"+file)
            name = file.replace(".tif", "")
            names_test.append(name)
            names_test = natsorted(names_test, key=lambda y: y.lower())
            with rasterio.open(template) as src:
                transform, width, height = calculate_default_transform(
                    src.crs, dst_crs, src.width, src.height, *src.bounds)
                kwargs = src.meta.copy()
                kwargs.update({
                    'crs': dst_crs,
                    'transform': transform,
                    'width': width,
                    'height': height
                })
                print('source', src.profile)
                with rasterio.open(file_dir + '/test/%s_projected.tif' % name, 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
                    for i in range(1, dst.count + 1):
                        reproject(
                            source=rasterio.band(dst, i),
                            destination=rasterio.band(dst, i),
                            src_transform=src.transform,
                            src_crs=src.crs,
                            dst_transform=transform,
                            dst_crs=dst_crs,
                            resampling=Resampling.nearest)
                    print('output', dst.profile)
                print(names_test)
```

Comment: Not sure about ratserio but in ArcGIS we usually have to recalculate statistics and rebuild pyramids to fix this issue.

Comment: Actually I can reproject this correctly in QGIS - but I have a load of these rasters to do (QGIS has a batch processing function but seems to take forever)

Comment: If you're getting values like 1.79769e+308 that indicates that the raster statistics need to be re-calculated. The raster is most likely correct but the values QGIS is showing are not updated after the projection. I work in an esri environment and get issues like this when doing any batch raster processing. In ArcGIS we can run the tool Calculate Statistics on the rasters and that fixes the values that are shown in the software. Maybe there is an equivalent in QGIS, not sure....